# How to apply randomly rotation value from array on different objects

Tags: maxscript

I have 10 box's and I want to apply a randomly rotation value from array, only on the Z axis.
The values in the array looks like this `[90 -90 180 -180]`.

```
myArry = {90 -90 180 -180}

for  o in selection do
(
    o.rotation (angleaxis ????? [0,0,1])
)
```

This is the script, of course it not working.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Random increments of 90° then?

```
for obj in selection do rotate obj (eulerAngles 0 0 (90 * random 0 4))
```